# Collectively describe and combine $N$ elements so that the result is invariant under permutation.

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, symmetry

I apologize that I am not a mathematician, but I got into this nice problem. :)

I have $N$ scalars defining $N$ properties $x_i$ for each integer $i = 1, 2, \dots, N$ associated with a corresponding set of $N$ elements that can undergo any kind of permutation. In other words, any vector obtained by a permutation of elements $x_i$ is an equally valid set for such properties.

1. What if now I want to describe "uniquely" (and without losing information) this set of properties, keeping in mind their permutation symmetry?
   Is there a way (e.g., a function, a linear combination) in which such $N$ objects $x_i$ could be combined to better describe their permutable ensemble?

**Example.** Suppose I want to describe a collection of five apples and their weights. Obviously, any vector obtained by the permutation of their five weights would describe it, but what if I want to find a unique representation? The sum or the product of all five weights are probably the most trivial way to globally represent it, but they are "reductive" and there must be a more general way to condense the whole information.

2. What happen instead if I have a set of properties that describe a property of *two* of such permutable objects? I guess a similar approach as above can be used.

**Example.** Suppose I want to collectively describe the spatial extension of a company that is occupying five identical buildings distributed on a geographical area. Suppose I can measure only the distance between each pair of buildings by $x_{ij}$. Now, to collectively describe such property, I would need to find a way to describe the $\frac12 N(N-1)$ distances according to the permutation symmetries (as all the buildings are identical).

Please note that sum or product would correspond to a reduction of the dimension and then alone their are not enough. Hence "describe" means to keep the maximum of information: so the function should ideally remain in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

I have also found some replies [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528474/function-invariant-under-cyclic-permutation-of-arguments), but this is not the most general case.   I guess group theory would do that, but I am not sure how to implement it. Thank you.

Comment: You might be talking about the notion of a "$N$-uniform hypergraph"

Comment: @halrankard maybe for problem 2?

Comment: Yes maybe. Are the $x_i$'s pairwise distinct? If so then then the *set* $X=\{x_{1} , \ldots , x_{N}\}$ is invariant under permutation. So for example $X$ is the same as $\{x_{2}, x_{1}, x_{3}, x_{4}, \ldots ,x_{N}\}$. If you allow $x_i = x_j$ for different $i$ and $j$ then use a *multiset* instead. Although I am not certain this what you want

Comment: Perhaps an example would help clear up what you are asking.

Comment: Its still unclear what "describe" means. From the example it sounds like you want a single number that codes all $N$ of the numbers. For the apple example observe that summing them up might not be good because different initial collections  could have the same total weight and so your "code" isn't unique to the initial collection. OTOH if summing them up is okay by you, then why is this not general enough? Anyway, it sounds like you want a function $F: \mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(\bar{x})= F(\bar{y})$ iff $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are the same up to a permutation. Is this right?

Comment: sorry - good point. "describe" means to keep the maximum of information: the sum or the product are valid but they are reductive (you loose dimension, in a way). So Ideally I'd go for $\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$. I am now thinking of combination and sum of product ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use symmetric polynomials : in addition to the sum and the product, you consider the sums of products of $k$ distinct elements, for $k = 0 , ..., n$

These numbers code the information you want. To prove this, you can use polynomials. For $k= 0, ..., n$, define $\sigma_k := \sum_{I\subseteq \lbrace 1,..., n\rbrace, |I| = k} \prod_{i\in I} x_i$. Note that $\sigma_0 = 1$.  Define the polynomial $P := \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \sigma_k X^{n-k}$. You can check that $P =  \prod_{i} (X-x_i)$. So the scalars $\sigma_k$ code the whole information, including possible doubles.

Example : $(X-x_1)(X-x_2)(X-x_3) = X^3 -(x_1+x_2+x_3)X^2 + (x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3)X - x_1x_2x_3$. Since the information you want is coded by the polynomial $(X-x_1)(X-x_2)(X-x_3)$, you can code it using its coefficients.

Remarks :

1. These identities are used in model theory to code finite sets in fields, which is not so different from the OP's request.
2. If I gave you the vector of the $\sigma_k$, you would know the polynomial. So, in a sense, you would know the $x_i$, since they are its roots. Yet, you wouldn't have an explicit formula expressing the $x_i$ in terms of the $\sigma_k$. Now, there are algorithms to find approximate values for the roots of a polynomial. In our case, we know how to bound the values of the roots in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial, so we would know "where to search".

Comment: thank you, it seems reasonable!  Could you just make an example (e.g. for N=4) so that I am sure I have understood?

Comment: Done for $n=3$.

Comment: +1 (and if may add): So you can make $F: \mathbb{R}^{N}\to \mathbb{R}^{N}$ such that $F(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N})=(\sigma_{1}, \ldots, \sigma_{N})$ (I exclude $\sigma_{0}$ since it's always $1$). This has the property that $F(\bar{x})=F(\bar{y})$ if and only if $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are the same up a permutation. For another such function let $F(\bar{x})$ be vector obtained by putting $x_{1}, \ldots , x_{N}$ in increasing order. This codes finite sets using the vocabulary of orderings instead of fields.

Comment: @halrankard Indeed. So your idea can be generalised to totally ordered sets, whereas mine works in fields. It happens that $\mathbb{R}$ is both ^^.

Comment: I had already though and used the ranked array. However, in the application I am interested (data science) this presents some disadvantages. The solution from @FiMePr seems to perfectly answer my needs :)

Comment: @gluuke Be aware that the converse construction is not computable with exact formulas. To retrieve the roots from the coefficients, you can (in general) only have numerical approximations.